# AndroidX migration - ImageView not scrollable anymore

Tags: android, androidx

I have a LinearLayout containing RelativeLayout with multiple ImageView (let me know if you need more information). 
When I use the below libraries from version 1.0.0 - I can scroll the screen even if scroll is done over an image.
But, if I upgrade one of the below libraries from v1.0.0 to v1.1.0, scroll is not working any more over the image:

- androidx.appcompat:appcompat
- com.google.android.material:material
- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview

In general scroll over other elements is working, but when an image get into the screen I can't scroll (unless I scroll using white space below or above the image). 
It's important to say that I have click event listener on each one of the images (imageView.setOnClickListener). 
When I remove the event listener, scroll is working as expected.

Thank you!

**Activity:**
[image]

**Content (inside activity):**
[image]

**Multiple images container (inside content):**
[image]

**Single Image (inside multiple images container):**
[image]

Comment: Can you share your layout code (XML) here?

Comment: Added screenshots to the qustion, the items are added programmatically.